# How do I interpret this PCA plot?

Tags: pca, data-visualization

I have to equally scaled variables that I want to combine into one PCA component measuring standards of living:

- slvpen: Standard of living of pensioners: 0 = Extremely bad, 10 = Extremely good.
- slvuemp: Standard of living of unemployed: 0 = Extremely bad, 10 = Extremely good.

Using R and the psych package, I have performed the PCA analysis:

Now, I want to visualise it using the factoextra package and get the following plot:

[image]

I have a hard time interpreting this plot.

1. What does the axes really show? Is Dim1 equal to PC1?
2. How do I interpret from the lengths of the arrows and the angle between them?
3. Lastly, can I say something about whether PC1 actually measures the latent concept in a good way using the plot?